# Set "never combine" in Windows 7 using the registry?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, windows-registry, regedit, combine

How do i set task bar buttons to "never combine" using the registry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the "never group taskbar buttons" feature.

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\TaskbarGlomLevel = 00000002
```

See KnifeySpoony's comment on an article about Windows 7 taskbar buttons at [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/make-the-windows-7-taskbar-work-more-like-windows-xp-or-vista/#comment-73355) for more information.

> TaskbarGlomLevel – Changes the
>   grouping so that the windows do not
>   turn into squares and overlap each
>   other. They will still group if you
>   have too many windows open. If you
>   want to never group windows, change
>   this value to 00000002.

Comment: Could you post this in .reg file form? Thanks!

Comment: @Aaron Franke Paste the contents of https://www.pastiebin.com/58b988beb8aea into a REG file. That should also set the option for all monitors on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Standing on the shoulders of Rob:

Via powershell ([src](https://github.com/neutmute/chocolatey-packs/blob/master/taskbar-never-combine/tools/chocolateyInstall.ps1)):

```
#http://superuser.com/questions/135015
$taskbarButtonsRegKey = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
if (((Get-ItemProperty -path $taskbarButtonsRegKey ).TaskbarGlomLevel ) -Ne 2)
{
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $taskbarButtonsRegKey -Name "TaskbarGlomLevel" -Value 00000002
}
```

Via chocolatey ([package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/taskbar-never-combine)):

```
choco install taskbar-never-combine
```

Comment: You may have to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` first as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Answer (score 0):

Rather old question, but here is my 2 cents **in VBScript to programmatically change the setting in registry then refresh the Taskbar** to take the change into account without rebooting or killing explorer.exe.

**Solution 1** : Requires having Excel installed to make the call to the Win32 API via VBA in order to refresh the Taskbar. A bit heavy solution, since it requires loading the entire application in background.

```
Dim WshShell, nKey
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

nKey= WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\TaskbarGlomLevel")

If nKey = 0 Then
    WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\TaskbarGlomLevel", 2, "REG_DWORD"
ElseIf nKey = 2 Then
    WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\TaskbarGlomLevel", 0, "REG_DWORD"
End If

'Private Const WM_WININICHANGE = &H1A&
'Private Const WM_SETTINGCHANGE = WM_WININICHANGE
'~~> DOES NOT WORK
'litterals seem required even if documentation should allow defining a constant with another constant
'https://www.vbsedit.com/html/61ad308e-6c17-4cd5-a9a6-8a47dc628ba1.asp
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513606/understanding-const-expression-in-vbscript
'Script56.chm

Private Const WM_SETTINGCHANGE = &H1A&
Private Const HWND_BROADCAST = &HFFFF&

'http://www.cpearson.com/excel/call.htm

Dim excel
Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim strMacro
strMacro = "CALL(""user32"",""SendMessageA"",""JJJJC""," & HWND_BROADCAST & "," & WM_SETTINGCHANGE & "," & 0 & ",""TraySettings"")"
excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro(strMacro)
```

**Solution 2** : More complicated, but usually quicker, using PowerShell to run an inline script making the call.

```
Dim WshShell, nKey
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

nKey= WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\TaskbarGlomLevel")

If nKey = 0 Then
    WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\TaskbarGlomLevel", 2, "REG_DWORD"
ElseIf nKey = 2 Then
    WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\TaskbarGlomLevel", 0, "REG_DWORD"
End If

command = "powershell.exe -nologo -command ""add-type -name user32 -namespace '' -memberDefinition '[DllImport(\""user32.dll\"", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)] public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, string lParam, uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out UIntPtr lpdwResult);'; $HWND_BROADCAST = [intptr]0xffff; $WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a; $result = [uintptr]::zero; [user32]::SendMessageTimeout($HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_SETTINGCHANGE, [uintptr]::Zero, \""TraySettings\"", 2, 5000, [ref]$result); """

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
objShell.run command,0
```