# Setting the Taskbar buttons to combine when full via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, taskbar

Is it possible to set the Taskbar buttons option to Combine when taskbar is full via a powershell command?
I've looked at [Set “never combine” in Windows 7 using the registry?](https://superuser.com/questions/135015/set-never-combine-in-windows-7-using-the-registry) but I'm after a PowerShell approach that works without logout.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any Powershell command will still require changing that registry value. Instead of logging out, try restarting the explorer process.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It works as @Qwilson stated. In Powershell code:

**1. Set the registy value**

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced -Name TaskbarGlomLevel -Value 1
```

**2. Stop Explorer as it will automatically restart itself.**

```
Stop-Process -Name "Explorer"
```

Comment: This needs one edit, you need to set the value of "TaskbarGlomLevel" equal to "1" not "0". 0 is for the default behavior which is "Always Combine, hide labels", 1 is for "Combine when taskbar is full" as asked in the original question.

Comment: Set the value to 2 if you want the taskbar buttons to never combine.